# am start cannot find main activity listed in manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, adb, activity-manager

I am trying to start an activity for an app (which I did not write in case you were wondering) through the adb shell. The manifest has the lines:

```
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MainActivity$mainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have tried using the the commands

```
adb shell am start -W com.pkg.name/MainActivity$mainActivity
adb shell am start -W com.pkg.name/.MainActivity$mainActivity
adb shell am start -W com.pkg.name/.MainActivity
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.pkg.name/MainActivity$mainActivity
adb shell am start -n com.pkg.name/MainActivity$mainActivity
etc...
```

and each and every one gives me the error:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.pkg.name/com.pkg.name.MainActivity}
does not exist.
```

It does however work when clicking on the app icon in the emulator, and by grepping the logcat output I find that the activity being launched is called `.MainActivity$mainActivit` or `.MainActivity`, they both show up in the output. Can someone tell me why `am start` is not working and how to in fact start this activity without manually clicking the icon?

**UPDATE:** The solution given by laalto is almost right. It turns out it was a problem with the `$` getting resolved as an environment variable, however the command he suggested doesn't quite do it. You need to put single quotes around to `<pkgname/activityname>` in addition to escaping the `$`.

Comment: Windows or OSX/Linux?

Comment: The host machine is running Linux.

Comment: question is if MainActivity$mainActivity is **static** inner class or **not static** inner class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In unix-like shells, `$` is a shell metacharacter so the `$mainActivity` expands to whatever value the environment variable `mainActivity` holds, likely an empty value in your case.

To escape it, use a backslash:

```
adb shell am start -W com.pkg.name/.MainActivity\$mainActivity
```

However, having an inner class as an entry point is sort of a code smell. Consider making the outer class your entry point. Then you wouldn't need `$` in any form.

Comment: I tried that, still not working, and just for the record, this is not my app. I can't do anything about how the developer decided on the entry point. :/

Comment: The manifest snippet has it as `mainActivity` and not `mainActivit`

Comment: That was actually a typo in the post. I went back and double checked that I had ran it properly. Still same result.

Comment: I got it to work using `adb shell am start -W 'com.pkg.name/.MainActivity\$mainActivity'` It needs to have the single quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
am start -n com.pkg.name/com.package.name.MainActivity$mainActivity
```

Good luck